# Projecting raster changes the range of values

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, values

I am trying to project a 1 second DEM from GDA94 to UTM56 in ArcMap using the Project Raster tool. I tried different methods: bilinear, cubic, nearest neighbor. Nevertheless, the values of the output rasters change dramatically and are nowhere near where they should be.

This is just a small test area but I will need to do the same operation for whole Australia to slice and project the DEM to 8 UTM zones.

How can I correct or fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is not unusual to see ranges/values changing when reprojecting a raster... try building statistics on the input and output rasters and see if the ranges are closer together. Is it possible you're only projecting a small portion of the input raster?

Comment: Did you make pointwise comparison of the height values at certain places or are you just looking at the min-max range?